# How many ways there are?

Tags: combinatorics

I cant solve the following problem. In how many ways we can divide 6 balls between 3 children if every children must receive at least 1 ball. I don't understand the problem. Is it permutations or what?

Comment: Are the balls the same or different?

Answer (score 1):

Give a ball to each chlid. Now you are left with the problem of how many ways to give 3 balls to 3 children. This is equal to the number of non-negative integer solutions of the equation
$$x+y+z=3.$$
And the answer is
$$\binom{3+3-1}{3}.$$

Comment: To make your statement more precise, say something like "This is equal to the number of non-negative integer solutions of the equation $x + y + z = 3$."

Comment: Thanks, wasnt clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

If the balls are identical, first give each child one ball.  Then lay the three remaining balls in a row with two "dividers".  How many ways can you arrange these three balls and two dividers?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the stars and bars (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))) to count the ways we can divide $6$ balls between $3$ children if every children must receive at least 1 ball.

For any pair of positive integers $n$ and $k$, the number of distinct $k$-tuples of positive integers whose sum is $n$ is given by the binomial coefficient
$$
{n-1\choose k-1}.
$$

Hence, the answer to the question is
$$
{6-1\choose3-1}={5\choose2}=10.
$$